# SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 Migration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I did a test migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 and deployed solution which has custom list definition which worked fine. But recently because of change request need to add field to list definition. After deploying the updated solution to SharePoint 2013 its throwing error as below

**Exception thrown while fetching field by internal name 'test' Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.  Please try again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFieldsSchemaXml**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 1):

Figured after migration some where in the database added old reference to the assemble. Used Feature Admin from codeplex and was able to uninstall the reference completely and install new solution and everything worked fine.

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new [SharePoint](https://aufait.in/sharepoint) 2013 Farm, Setup necessary configurations.
2. Backup - Restore SharePoint 2010 Content Databases to SharePoint 2013's SQL Server (or perform a detach-attach process)
3. Verify content databases by running: Test-SPContentDatabase from the Target SharePoint 2013 farm.
4. Attach Content Databases to SharePoint 2013 web application by running: Mount-SPContentDatabase
5. Upgrade Site Collections to move them into SharePoint 2013.